# Explicitly specify sort order for mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

If I have:

```
ID | Title
1  | Shirt
2  | CD
3  | Cap
4  | Mp3
5  | Badge
```

If I want to sort by this order: 4, 2, 5, 3,1. Is there a way to do an sql query where you explicitly specify this? Something like:

```
select * from TABLE order by ID(4,2,5,3,1) ??
```

Comment: How about you introduce a "position" column and order the items exactly how you want and query the rows ordered by position? Relying on ordering things by ID-s is just... dumb.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, you were surprisingly close. It's a simple as:

```
select * from TABLE order by field(ID,4,2,5,3,1)
```

Comment: Nice, is that MySQL-specific?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes - it's more mysql "funk", but all that "non-standards-compliant" stuff is just so handy it's too hard to resist!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a CASE in the ORDER BY as a rudimentary lookup table:

```
select *
from your_table
order by
    case id
        when 4 then 1
        when 2 then 2
        when 5 then 3
        when 3 then 4
        when 1 then 5
    end
```

Comment: Great line. Very useful

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from TABLE order by ID=1,ID=3,ID=5,ID=2,ID=4;
```

YOU RUN THIS AND LET ME KNOW ABOUT YOUR DOUBT.