# sequelize order base on specific condition

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Consider I have users table and I want to filter some of them with "where:{id:[3,1,2]}"
and I want result to be in same order of ids that I just set, means first return user with id of 3 then user with id of 1 and last return user with id of 2.
How can I tell sequelize to do that?

```
await db.Users.findAll({
    where:{id:[3,1,2]},
});
```

Comment: i think the problem already solved on [tag:mysql] side. but the question would be, can we implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802944/explicitly-specify-sort-order-for-mysql-query) using sequelize?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the desired order in Sequelize when using a where condition with specific IDs, you can use the order option along with the literal function.

I think it should work

```
// Your list of user IDs *****
const userIds = [3, 1, 2];

// Query to fetch users with specified IDs in the given order *****
const users = await User.findAll({
  where: {
     id: {
       [Op.in]: userIds,
     },
  },
  order: [
      Sequelize.literal(`FIELD(id, ${userIds.join(',')})`),
   ],
});
```

In the example above :

- Op.in is used to filter users with the specified IDs.
- Sequelize.literal is used to provide a raw SQL expression for ordering based on the desired order of IDs. The FIELD function is used to specify the order.

**Note: Using Sequelize.literal makes the query vulnerable to SQL injection if the input is not sanitized. Ensure that the userIds array is sanitized before using it in the query to prevent potential security issues.**

Comment: Thank you Daniel,It's very good question